# How to add column before specific column with JS

Tags: javascript

[image]

I can get column index from select tag. Select tag options are populated from array which I get from the header row of table.

I have code which is adding column after last column in table.

How must I change my code to add column after specific column index?

On change in select tag I get the column index.

```js
 var arrHead = new Array(); // array for header.
document.getElementById("add-i-tableID").addEventListener("click", function(){
   
    arrHead = [ 'Customer', 'Article', 'Amount'];
  
        var empTable = document.createElement('table');
        empTable.setAttribute('id', 'empTable'); // table id.

        var tr = empTable.insertRow(-1);
        for (var h = 0; h < arrHead.length; h++) {
            var th = document.createElement('th'); // create table headers
            th.innerHTML = arrHead[h];
            th.style.border= '1px solid ';
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        var div_table = document.getElementById('i_tableID');
        div_table.appendChild(empTable);  // add the TABLE to the container.
   
});var selectedIndexT = 0;
document.getElementById("add-i-colID").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var th = document.createElement('th'); // create table headers
  var colname1 = prompt("Please enter name of  the column");
  th.innerHTML = colname1;
  th.style.border = '1px solid';

  var xcvbn = document.getElementById('empTable');
  var xcvbnR = xcvbn.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  xcvbnR[0].appendChild(th);

  for (i = 1; i < xcvbnR.length; i++) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var ele1 = document.createElement('input');
    ele1.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    ele1.setAttribute('value', '');
    ele1.style.color = "#8dbeb6";
    td.appendChild(ele1);
    xcvbnR[i].appendChild(td);
  }
});
```

```html
  <button id="add-i-tableID">Add test table</button>
 <button id="add-i-colID">Add column</button>

 <div id="i_tableID" ></div>
```

Comment: can you create a working example here so that it's easy to help.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0rj4hce8/    First click on add test table. Change var selectedIndexT = 0; to var selectedIndexT = 1; manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You can make use of [`Node.insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

- When the `Add` button is clicked, grab the `selectedIndex`,

  - If it is `0` throw an alert asking the user to select a valid column.
  - If it is a valid index ask the user to provide the column name and then create a `th` element with the column name provided.
- Now, grab the `table`, the header row (`thead tr`) and all `th` elements inside the header row.
- Next, using `insertBefore` and `selectedIndex` insert the newly created `th` at its appropriate location.
- Finally grab all body rows and using the same logic insert empty `td` elements at the correct location in all body rows.
- And then you can update the options inside the dropdown.

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Get the selected index
  const selIdx = document.querySelector("#add-col").selectedIndex;

  // If selected index is zero throw an alert
  if (!selIdx) return alert("Please select a column");

  // Ask for the column name
  const colName = prompt("Enter column name");

  // Create a `th` with the provided column name
  const th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerText = colName;

  // Grab necessary elements from the DOM
  const table = document.querySelector("table");
  const tr = table.querySelector("thead tr");
  const allHeaders = table.querySelectorAll("th");

  // Insert the `th` at appropriate location
  tr.insertBefore(th, allHeaders[selIdx - 1]);

  // Fill body rows with empty `td` elements
  const tbody = table.querySelector("tbody");
  Array.from(tbody.children).forEach(function(row) {
    const emptyTd = document.createElement("td");
    row.insertBefore(emptyTd, row.children[selIdx - 1])
  })

  updateSelectOptions()
});

function updateSelectOptions() {
  const headers = document.querySelectorAll("table thead th");
  const select = document.querySelector("#add-col");

  // Empty the select node
  select.innerHTML = "";

  // Insert the default option
  const opt = document.createElement("option");
  opt.innerText = "Select a column";
  select.appendChild(opt)

  // Add other options based on the headers
  Array.from(headers).forEach(function(header) {
    const opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.innerText = header.innerText;
    select.appendChild(opt)
  });
}
```

```css
form * {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.75rem 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}

table th {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: slateblue;
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Customer</th>
      <th>Article</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Laptop</td>
      <td>1000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Amanda</td>
      <td>Television</td>
      <td>750</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<form>
  <label for="add-col">Add Column Before:</label>
  <select id="add-col">
    <option>Select a column</option>
    <option>Customer</option>
    <option>Article</option>
    <option>Amount</option>
  </select>
  <button>Add</button>
</form>
```